# When using align-items whole content is not visible

Tags: html, css

While using `align-items: center` the whole content is not visible as you can see in below snippet .

The work around this problem are removing `align-items: center` but when there is less content it will not be centered.

Applying a `max-height` or fix `height` to the class `inner` by this way scroll bar will be created on `inner` but this also don't always solve the problem as sometimes when `window` `height` is less than also content is hidden.

Are there any way to cope up with this problem or have to use a different properties for centering the `inner`

```css
#outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--white);
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*This auto in main code*/
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 8px 16px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: sticky;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 900;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  margin: 0 0 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="btn">X</div>
    <p> 1st part </p>
    <p> 2nd part </p>
    <p> 3rd part </p>
    <p> 4th part </p>
    <p> 5th part </p>
    <p> 5th part </p>
    <p> 5th part </p>
    <p> 5th part </p>
    <p> 5th part </p>
    <p> 6th part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>
    <p> other part </p>

    <p> other part </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

But with the suggested answer `sticky` property won't work which is inside `inner` class . By the way it is still not visible(sticky part) now also but when content is visible , it is not working as sticky .

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't make your outer div fixed?

Comment: Yup but as fixed is need the above link to question will perfectly solve the problem @Royalty . I will keep this question so that anyone come searching something like this will get to right link .

Comment: @TemaniAfif that way `sticky` property wont work which is inside `inner`